# Obtaining Generated Unique Version from Maven Snapshots

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

As per [the manual](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html#pom-relationships-sect-snapshot-versions%7C), with Maven 3 we're forced to use `uniqueSnapshots=true`. This means that each deployment of `1.0-SNAPSHOT` is actually backed by some unique, canonical ID e.g. `1.0-20080207-230803-1`.

As a result, invoking `mvn deploy` produces artifacts whose canonical version cannot be determined before the `mvn` executable is invoked.

Therefore, if one wishes to invoke any operations on the unique ID generated afterwards, one must try to extract the generated ID from the maven executable after `mvn deploy` completes.

Is there any such mechanism to obtain the unique ID?

For example, `mvn deploy` will produce the following output:

```
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/io/airlift/slice/0.11-SNAPSHOT/slice-0.11-20150220.165404-2.jar
```

But there seems to be no way to access the ID `0.11-20150220.165404-2` without parsing the output from Maven.

Example scenario: mvn build results in a new (unique) artifact being pushed to an internal repository manager. After that completes, we wish to push a notification over HTTP to inform some remote application of a new SNAPSHOT version of the application.

Although our repository manager allows us to query for the latest SNAPSHOT version, this is *not* the same as being able to pass absolute references to specific versions around.

Answer (score 4):

The maven-deploy-plugin does not store the deployment timestamp in system properties.

If you want to take a look at the source code (and maybe make an enhancement request), this deployment timestamp is calculated in class [`org.apache.maven.artifact.transform.SnapshotTransformation`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-artifact-manager/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/transform/SnapshotTransformation.html) by the method [`getDeploymentTimestamp`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-artifact-manager/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/transform/SnapshotTransformation.html#getDeploymentTimestamp%28%29) of the project [`maven-artifact-manager`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-artifact-manager/source-repository.html).

The final version of the deployed artifact is calculated in method [`construcVersion`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-artifact-manager/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/transform/SnapshotTransformation.html#constructVersion%28org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.Versioning,%20java.lang.String%29) : the `SNAPSHOT` is replaced by `timestamp-buildNumber`, where `timestamp` is the result of `getDeploymentTimestamp` and `buildNumber` is an increment.

It should be possible to store this constructed version with `System.setProperty("something", version)`; and then access it in the `pom.xml` with `${something}`.