# Gradle: How to extract the specific SNAPSHOT version after deploy to nexys

Tags: java, maven, gradle

When gradle publishes artifacts to maven which have a SNAPSHOT versioning, then gradle generates a specific built version like this:

example-1.32-SNAPSHOT.jar

becomes:

example-1.32-20150928.115422-5.jar

How can we extract this specific version from gradle (e.g. not maven!) such that we can pass it on to the next step in our build pipeline?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26548698/1743880

Comment: Does gradle use the same code for publishing?